# How to diagnose a faulty driver causing random restarts?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash

I am running Windows 7 x64. Ever since I installed the OS on my machine a couple of months ago, there has been random restarts occasionally.

- My previous OS was Windows 8 and I did not have this issue.
- The restart is not preceded by anything - no BSOD, no application hangs etc. It feels like somebody just hit the reset button on the motherboard

This leads me to believe that this is a crash in kernel space, i.e. either the OS itself, or one of the drivers, crashed. I suspect it might be the Nvidia display driver, or one of the ASUS motherboard drivers which rumors to be buggy according to a few forums.

What logs can I look for if it is a driver crash?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the System Properties - Startup and Recovery Settings or an export of the values under this registry key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\` just to confirm what happens when the computer encounters a bugcheck.  I would set it to a complete dump and then run verifier.exe, choose Standard Settings - Select drivers names from a list.  Then check all non-Microsoft drivers.  After rebooting.  If the drivers misbehave, it should then bugcheck the computer and you should get a full dump to analzye.

Comment: @HelpingHand sounds like an answer. Would you mind putting the steps in more detail in the answer box below?

Comment: If you suspect the display driver. Have you updated it?  Why are you using the drivers shipped with the motherboard, those are out of date, go to the ASUS website and download the **current drivers**.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated them numerous times. Also note that the latest software release is not necessarily the best.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Answer (score 1):

If you find that your PC is crashed because of a driver fault, the best way to find the causing driver is using windbg.

- Check the if you machine has crash dump available. See https://serverfault.com/questions/306812/where-is-minidump-file for the exact location of the dump files.
- Install WinDbg; See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/
- Load the dump file into WinDbg, using File->Open Crash dump
- In the command window at the bottom, enter !analyze - v, and press Enter.
- this will generate a report, which gives you a hint which driver is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful troubleshooting methods :

- Search the Event Viewer for useful error messages for both software and hardware.
- See if [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) finds any Windows crash files - it will highlight the crashing driver.
- Try [AppCrashView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) for analyzing application crashes.
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
  to check system validity.
- If you can boot and still work in
  [Safe Mode With Network](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-start-windows-7-in-safe-mode-2624540),
  see if the crash happens in this mode.
  If it does not happen, then the problem is with some installed
  third-party startup product, and you may use
  [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
  to turn off startup programs until you find the problem.
- [Run Diagnostics to Check Your System for Memory Problems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700221.aspx), just in case.