# Fix for frequent crashes on a dell 2-in-1 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, crash, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 laptop.

Model: Dell Inspiron 13-5378.
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500 CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.90GHz
Installed Memory: 8 GB
64-bit Windows 10, x64 based processor.

It usually crashes when there is a game running. It crashes even when a GBA emulator is running. Some times the laptop can handle a game client running by itself and nothing else running. But most of the times it crashes when any game is running.

The laptop is around 6 months old. In the first couple of months it didn't crash. It hasn't been damaged in any way.

Comment: [Windbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) is a required tool to diagnose the reason your system is crashing.  Questions like, [How to diagnose a faulty driver causing random restarts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1297489/how-to-diagnose-a-faulty-driver-causing-random-restarts/1306393#1306393), will get you started in the process of identifying the reason your system is actually crashing.

Answer (score -1):

I really hate the way Intel is SKUing the mobile processors these days.

You're staring down a couple of potential issues here.   Let's frame the problem with things you can't actually do anything about. The first, you may surprised to know, is your processor.  It's not just an i7-7500.  It's an i7-7500U.   The U-series are all "underpower" which means the processor itself may have some i7 tech on it, but it's an underclocked processor that only has two processor cores. When comparing specs to video game requirements, it's best to consider this similar to an i3: you've got a dual-core machine, so that will severely limit your ability to multitask compared to a desktop.  When you game, you're going to want to run only the game, because it's likely going to tax the processor heavily if it's a multithreaded game.   Those which are not will use the same core as your operating system, but you can change that manually once the process is running in Task Manager.  In this case, I don't think it will make much of a difference, as you're also limited by the 2.9ghz turbo clockspeed. At those frequencies, you should check and see if what you actually have is a 7200U.

The second problem is that it's using the Intel on-die graphics processor.  This is part of the i7 and can't be physically upgraded.

This means most of what you can change is all software.   Follow these steps:

1. Go to the Dell website and ensure you have the latest versions of all drivers.
2. Uninstall bloatware.  Nobody needs a weather widget when Cortana knows how to look outside all on its own.  Anything labelled as a special software feature for buying from Dell is garbage with makeup on. If it came with a free "trial" that has expired of an antivirus program, remove it and use a free one.  Sometimes the hooks these have in the OS seem to cause performance issues, either due to ironic programming or a ninja attempt to push you to purchase the full version (speculation, but never trust someone who makes money off of your frustrations).
3. It looks like that machine has a 2.5" HDD and not an SDD.  If so, defragmenting can't hurt.
4. Using the full virus scanner, run a scan, boot-time if possible.  There may be something lurking that is messing with your stuff.
5. When you play a game, run only that.  If you absolutely must run something else, like Discord or Ventrilo or Teamspeak or whatever, keep it to just that. *No web browsers* as Javascript these days can be demanding on your machine in ways you may not realize.
6. Don't Alt-Tab your games on a machine with less than 4 cores.  It's better to run them in a window if something else has to be running at the same time.  Alt-Tab can interrupt a game's internal scripts if it's running full-screen.

Answer (score -1):

Open the start menu and search for "event viewer". Filter the events to critical/ warning. Search for the time when this occured. You'll likely see a faulty driver message or a hardware event.
For 1: Go to your video cards homepage and download the newest drivers.
For 2: Your system might be overheating. Try cleaning dust out of your notebook (blow air into the ventilators location, use a pin to stop the vent from spinning)